# C# WinForm DataGridView without any padding/marging

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I try using gridview, but I don't understand how to disable include padding/marging in cells.
[program view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmFPx.jpg)

Designer code here:

```
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        this.dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
        this.dataGridView1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
        this.dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(102)))));
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(102)))));
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
        this.dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 9);
        this.dataGridView1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
        this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        this.dataGridView1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.None;
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(319, 186);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
```

Is it possible to remove these gaps at all to zero, so that the text almost touches from different cells?

Try2 look:
[try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fDqf.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change padding for all cells in a single DataGridView column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283234/change-padding-for-all-cells-in-a-single-datagridview-column)

Comment: @EricSchaefer No. I use only default style with zero padding... Any ideas?

Comment: [DataGridViewCell.GetContentBounds](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewCell.cs,1776) -> Override [protected virtual Rectangle GetContentBounds()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewCell.cs,1790) + Override [protected virtual Size GetPreferredSize()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewCell.cs,2594)